# how to prove an arbitrary language can be accepted by an Infinite state automata

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, pushdown-automaton

we know that language accepted by a DFA can also be accepted by an ISA for DFA is a special case of ISA, so about an arbitrary language? How to prove it?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Define transitions such that every word in the language has a corresponding accepting state, with whatever supporting states are needed to reach those accepting states (a structure analogous to a trie - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This automaton is deterministic and will accept any language.

Comment: however, I think the definition of an automaton accepting a language has to be unique, because If L(M) = L, L has to be ALL the string that can be accepted by this automaton。So how you construct an automaton that accepts every language?